# Odd integral Stiefel–Whitney classes in terms of even ones

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces, stiefel-whitney

As computed in various places (e.g. in [Brown - The Cohomology of $B\mathrm{SO}_n$ and $B\mathrm O_n$ with Integer Coefficients](https://doi.org/10.2307/2044298)), the integral cohomology ring of $B\mathrm{O}(n)$ (and similarly $B\mathrm{SO}(n)$) is generated by the Pontrjagin classes, possibly an Euler class, and the elements
$$
\beta(w_1w_{2i_1} \dotsm w_{2i_k}), ~~\text{and} ~~~ \beta(w_{2i_1} \dotsm w_{2i_k}), ~~~~ 0 < i_1 < \dotsb < i_k < \lfloor \tfrac{n-1}{2}\rfloor,
$$
subject to various relations. Here $\beta$ is the Bockstein homomorphism $H^*(~, \mathbb{Z}_2) \to H^*(~, \mathbb{Z})$, the $w_i$ are the Stiefel–Whitney classes and the generator involving $w_1$ is only there in the $B\mathrm{O}(n)$ case.

On the other hand, the integral Stiefel–Whitney classes $W_i = \beta(w_{i-1})$ are all non-zero in $B\mathrm{O}(n)$ (an argument is, e.g., given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3694159/which-integral-steifel-whitney-classes-are-universally-0)), hence also the even integral classes $W_{2i}$ must be expressible in terms of the generators above. How? I could not find this in the standard references and I am not familiar enough with the properties of the Bockstein homomorphism to derive this myself.

Comment: Did you mean to ask about the classes $W_{2i}$? The classes $W_{2i+1}=\beta(w_{2i})$ are included in your list of generators.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sq{Sq}$The odd classes $\beta(w_{2i})$ are part of your list of generators.

More interesting (and maybe what you wanted to ask?) is where the classes $\beta(w_{2i+1})$ are.

For this one needs some basic facts about $\beta$, namely that

- $\rho \circ \beta = \Sq^1$ and
- $\beta \circ \rho = 0$,

where $\rho$ is the reduction mod 2 homomorphism $H^*(\cdot, \mathbb{Z})\to H^*(\cdot, \mathbb{Z}_2)$.
The first follows from the construction of Steenrod squares, the second form the definition of $\beta$ as the connecting homomorphism for $\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\cdot 2} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow\rho \mathbb{Z}_2$.

One can then use that $\Sq^1(w_{2i})=w_1 w_{2i} + w_{2i+1}$ to see that $\beta(w_{2i+1})=\beta(w_1 w_{2i})$, since $\beta$ is additive and $\Sq^1(w_{2i})$ lies in the image of $\rho$.

Comment: Ok, so this expresses the $W_{2i}$ in terms of generators over $B\mathrm{O}(n)$. Does this mean that the $W_{2i}$ are zero over $B\mathrm{SO}(n)$?

Comment: Yes. The same equations hold in BSO, but $w_1$ vanishes there, so $\beta(w_{2i+1})=\beta(w_1 w_{2i})=0$.